# closing a connection with twisted

Tags: python, tcp, twisted

Various connections - e.g. those created with [`twisted.web.client.getPage()`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.1.0/api/twisted.web.client.getPage.html) seem to leak - they hang around indefinitely, since the OS time-out is measured in hours - if the server doesn't respond timely.  And putting a time-out on the deferred you get back is *deprecated*.

How can you track the requests you have open, and close them forcefully in your twisted program?

(Forcefully closing connections that have timed-out in application logic is important to making a twisted server that scales; various reactors have different limits on the number of open file descriptors they allow - `select` being as low as 1024!  So please help twisted users keep the open connections count nice and trimmed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getPage` accepts a `timeout` parameter.  If you pass a value for it and the response is not fully received within that number of seconds, the connection will be closed and the `Deferred` returned by `getPage` will errback.

Comment: will test to see that the open file descriptor count stops growing, thx!